# Getting candlestick chart to display properly using a text / .txt file of historic stock prices in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, quantmod, geom-bar, candlestick-chart

Hell there,
I have purchased the historic intraday prices of the S&P 500 (1min through 1hour) back through 2005 because most stock charting packages stop reporting intraday prices around 2016 or 2011. I have successfully imported the prices and gotten R to only read market hours, excluding premarket and aftermarket. Two problems exist. First, I need to get the chart to not show saturday and sunday. The bigger problem is that the plot is NOT showing candlesticks, but bars and they are very hard to read. I have tried increasing the size via (size = 4), but the bars overlap and are still not candlesticks. How can I get these to show as proper candlesticks? thank you

```
library(quantmod)
library(tidyquant)
library(tidyverse)
library(ggplot2)
library(readr)
library(ggforce)
library(dplyr)


dir <-  "E:/Stock Trading/Historical Data/SPY_qjrt28"
setwd(dir)

data <- read_csv("SPY_30min.txt", 
        col_names = FALSE)
               
names(data) <- tolower(c("DateTime", "Open", "High", "Low", "Close", "Volume"))
data

#clean the data
write_rds(data, "cleaned.rds")
read_rds("cleaned.rds")

spy30m <- read_rds("cleaned.rds")
firstwave <- filter(spy30m, datetime >= as.Date('2009-03-02'), datetime <= as.Date('2009-03-19'))

# adding more time objects to the dataset
data <- data %>%
  mutate(hour = hour(datetime),
         minute = minute(datetime),
         hms = as_hms(datetime))

# is the hour function working as expected? Yes!
data %>%
  select(datetime, hour) %>%
  sample_n(10)

# look at bins of observations at 30 minute intervals. Looks good!
data %>%
  group_by(hms) %>%
  summarise(count = n()) %>%
  arrange(hms) %>% 
  print(n=100)

# filter the dataset to only include the times during regular market hours
data_regularmkt <- data %>%
  # `filter` is the dplyr function that limits the number of observations in a data frame
  # `between` function takes 3 arguments: an object/variable, a lower bound value, and upper bound value
  filter(between(hms, as_hms("09:30:00"), as_hms("16:00:00")))

# look at it again
data_regularmkt %>%
  group_by(hms) %>%
  summarise(count = n()) %>%
  arrange(hms) %>% 
  print(n=100)

###########

firstwave <- filter(spy30m, datetime >= as.Date('2009-03-06'), datetime <= as.Date('2009-03-19'))

ggplot(firstwave, aes(x = datetime, y = close)) +
  geom_candlestick(aes(open = open, high = high, low = low, close = close, size = 3))
```

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example.

Answer (score 0):

Say we have a data frame `df` with the columns date (dttm format), open, high, low, close.

To overcome the issue that non-trading hours are shown, my first idea was to use another x-axis scale. Here's with a row-index.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
library(tidyquant)

df <- df %>% 
  arrange(date) %>% 
  mutate(i = row_number())

# this is for the x-axis labels
df_x <- df %>% 
  group_by(d = floor_date(date, "day")) %>% 
  filter(date %in% c(min(date)))

df %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = i)) +
  geom_candlestick(aes(open = open, low = low, high = high, close = close)) + 
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = df_x$i,
                     labels = df_x$date)
```

The problem then is that if a contract is halted during trading hours, there will be no data too just like with night or weekend. However, these times you probably want to show anyway.

One could probably play with dplyr functions' `complete` or `expand` to fix the data first and still use my solution of plotting over an index x-scale.

Easier could be to use the plotly library.

```
plt <- plot_ly(data = df, x = ~date, 
               open = ~open, close = ~close,
               high = ~high, low = ~low,
               type="candlestick") 
plt
```

This is to hide the non-trading hours:

```
plt %>% layout(showlegend = F, xaxis = list(rangebreaks=
                                        list(
                                          list(bounds=list(17, 9),
                                               pattern="hour")),#hide hours outside of 9am-5pm
                                      dtick=86400000.0/2,
                                      tickformat="%H:%M\n%b\n%Y"))
```

More information can be found here: https://plotly.com/r/time-series/#hiding-nonbusiness-hours and https://plotly.com/r/candlestick-charts/

As for you not liking the appearance of tidyquant's `geom_candlestick`, I also suggest you try out Plotly.